# Form is submitted with "null" but will be object after submit

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

After hours of debugging the complete `vendor/symfony/form/Form` I was only able to find out that the `FormEvents::SUBMIT` converts my `null` value to `Object`.

This is my code.

```
$form = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, new Person());
$form->submit($request->request->all(), false);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
{
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $entity;
}

return $form->getErrors(true, true);
```

Then I send this request.

```
POST /api/persons/e3d90966-b2e7-4503-959f-da989c73c185
{
    "name": {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}
}
```

It sets the name of the person to `John Doe`.

**Now I want to clear it:**

```
POST /api/persons/e3d90966-b2e7-4503-959f-da989c73c185
{
    "name": null
}
```

And et voilà: The name is still `John Doe`.

**I'm using a custom type:**

```php
class NameType extends AbstractType
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
        ;

        $builder->addModelTransformer(new NameTransformer($this->manager));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Name::class,
            'compound' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

**And is used via:**

```php
$builder
    ->add('name', NameType::class)
;
```

**Some more informations:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting

```
{
    "name": null
}
```

That is the parent form being empty, so without the child form fields you have not passed any values for fields nor the fields themselves. You don't submit a new value for the fields, so nothing is changed.
I think you need to explicitly set each of the individual field values to `null` in order for this to work. One of the following examples should do the trick:

```
POST /api/persons/e3d90966-b2e7-4503-959f-da989c73c185
{
    "name": {"firstName": null, "lastName": null}
}
```

or

```
POST /api/persons/e3d90966-b2e7-4503-959f-da989c73c185
{
    "name": {"firstName": "", "lastName": ""}
}
```